# Find out enode url

Tags: truffle, quorum, enode, cakeshop

I am running seven Quorum nodes, which I have set up the way this example describes it: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/building-dapps-for-quorum-private-enterprise-blockchains

Afterwards I have installed [Cakeshop](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/cakeshop) and want it to show the seven nodes in its GUI to play around with them. For this I need the enode url of every peer. Is there a way to find out the enode urls via Truffle or geth or web3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the enodes for the current standard Quorum 7Nodes example in the [*permissioned-nodes.json*](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/blob/master/examples/7nodes/permissioned-nodes.json) file:

```
[
  "enode://ac6b1096ca56b9f6d004b779ae3728bf83f8e22453404cc3cef16a3d9b96608bc67c4b30db88e0a5a6c6390213f7acbe1153ff6d23ce57380104288ae19373ef@127.0.0.1:21000?discport=0&raftport=50401",
  "enode://0ba6b9f606a43a95edc6247cdb1c1e105145817be7bcafd6b2c0ba15d58145f0dc1a194f70ba73cd6f4cdd6864edc7687f311254c7555cc32e4d45aeb1b80416@127.0.0.1:21001?discport=0&raftport=50402",
  "enode://579f786d4e2830bbcc02815a27e8a9bacccc9605df4dc6f20bcc1a6eb391e7225fff7cb83e5b4ecd1f3a94d8b733803f2f66b7e871961e7b029e22c155c3a778@127.0.0.1:21002?discport=0&raftport=50403",
  "enode://3d9ca5956b38557aba991e31cf510d4df641dce9cc26bfeb7de082f0c07abb6ede3a58410c8f249dabeecee4ad3979929ac4c7c496ad20b8cfdd061b7401b4f5@127.0.0.1:21003?discport=0&raftport=50404",
  "enode://3701f007bfa4cb26512d7df18e6bbd202e8484a6e11d387af6e482b525fa25542d46ff9c99db87bd419b980c24a086117a397f6d8f88e74351b41693880ea0cb@127.0.0.1:21004?discport=0&raftport=50405",
  "enode://eacaa74c4b0e7a9e12d2fe5fee6595eda841d6d992c35dbbcc50fcee4aa86dfbbdeff7dc7e72c2305d5a62257f82737a8cffc80474c15c611c037f52db1a3a7b@127.0.0.1:21005?discport=0&raftport=50406",
  "enode://239c1f044a2b03b6c4713109af036b775c5418fe4ca63b04b1ce00124af00ddab7cc088fc46020cdc783b6207efe624551be4c06a994993d8d70f684688fb7cf@127.0.0.1:21006?discport=0&raftport=50407"
]
```

If you have an older version, they are in *static-nodes.json*.